# Implementation of Observer Pattern Based on UML diagram

Tags: java, design-patterns, interface, observer-pattern

**Question**

I'm having trouble understanding the following UML-diagram of the **Observer** pattern from the "Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software". Could anyone explain me why my Java implementation is wrong and what I have to change to implement it correctly?

**UML-Diagram**

[image: UML-Diagram]

**Attempted (but wrong) implementation**

```java
public interface Subject {
    
    public static final List<Observer> observers = new ArrayList<Observer>();
    
    public void attach(Observer o);
    public void detach(Observer o);
    public void notifyObservers();
}

public interface Observer { 
    public void update();
}

public class ConcreteSubject implements Subject {
    
    private String subjectState;

    @Override
    public void attach(Observer o) {
        observers.add(o);   
    }

    @Override
    public void detach(Observer o) {
        observers.remove(o);
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyObservers() {
        for (Observer o : observers) {
            o.update();
        }       
    }
    
    public String getState() {
        return subjectState;
    }
    
    public void setState() {
        subjectState += "x";
    }
}

public class ConcreteObserver implements Observer {
    
    private ConcreteSubject subject;
    public String observerState;

    @Override
    public void update() {
        observerState = subject.getState();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

One problem is that you have a static list of observers in `Subject` so *all* subjects share the same observers. However, the pattern requires that each individual subject has its own observers so put the list into `ConcreteSubject` and make it an instance field.

Another problem is that your `ConcreteObserver` has a field of type `ConcreteSubject`. It should, however, not know about the concrete implementation of `Subject` so the field should only have the type `Subject`.

**Edit**: Actually the UML diagram requires the concrete observer to know about the concrete subject in order to be able to call `getState()` so the above paragraph is not true in your case - this should not be a problem here.

However, in reality I would actually have another interface that extends `Subject` and hides the implementation of `ConcreteSubject` from the observer.

**Edit 2**:

As has been suggested you could also use an abstract class to handle the observers of a subject. That could be a class in between `Subject` and `ConcreteSubject` or even `Subject` itself but since Java doesn't support multiple inheritance I'd often use some other approach and make `Subject` just an interface.

The easiest implementation would then be to have `ConcreteSubject` maintain the list of observers but in a real world application you'd not want to have developers do that or rely on them implementing it correctly.

Instead you could use a central registry that maintains the list of observers for each subject and which the subject uses to inform its observers. Many dependency injection frameworks out there operate in a way like that, i.e. whenever a "subject" changes they will inform its observers about that event.

Comment: Alternatively, make `Subject` an abstract class instead of an interface, so that it can have an (instance) field `observers` and implementations of `attach()`, `detach()`, and `notifyObservers()`.  That would be closer to the UML.

Comment: "One problem is that you have a static list of observers" - I'll say that more than just "a problem" LOL

Comment: @Thomas: Thanks and of course it makes sense. But how do I interpret the arrow from Subject to Observer? From what I understand I would interpret it as "Subject has many Observers". If I make the observers field a field of ConcreteSubject, it looks more like "ConcreteSubject has many Observers". So wouldn't it be more accurate to make a double arrow from ConcreteSubject to ConcreteObserver?

Comment: @MoritzWolff you interpret that arrow as "calls" or "uses"

Comment: @MoritzWolff yes, that's true. The diagram wasn't made for Java (as can be seen by the method names) and in another language it probably would make sense to make `Subject` an actual class and have `ConcreteSubject` inherit from it. In Java where multiple inheritance is not supported I'd not use an abstract superclass for `Subject` but make it an interface so that anything that already has a superclass could be a `Subject` as well.

Comment: @MoritzWolff to clarify a point made by Thomas, UML is supposed to be "language agnostic." However sometimes, there are limits or constraints based on the language. So, as a developer, you have to be aware and explore what are the accepted equivalents for the language you're using.

Comment: @hfontanez and Thomas: Thanks for the clarification. This doesn't make it easier to study design patterns, but at least I know why I was confused now!

Comment: @MoritzWolff one more thing... about the arrows you were asking about, do not mistake them with aggregation or composition. Those have a diamond pointing towards the "owner". Aggregation has the "white" diamond while composition has the dark diamond. And you are right, it should've been an aggregation relationship.

Comment: @hfontanez What did I say that suggests I could have confused the two?

Comment: @MoritzWolff you said "ConcreteSubject has many Observers". You were right thinking that way, but that is not what the arrow represent. In my opinion, that should've been an  aggregation arrow. I just wanted to explain the difference between what the actual arrow shown represent and what should've been for correctness.

Comment: @hfontanez I see, thanks for your effort - your answers helped.

Comment: @MoritzWolff for more info on that, you could read this blog on the subject https://www.professorfontanez.com/2016/02/aggregation-and-composition.html